# D3: unable to access data within anonymous function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create tooltips based on this tutorial
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html#_svg_element_tooltips
Jump to: HTML div Tooltips

I have an issue though. I am unable to pass a data to anonymous function. Refer to ISSUE HERE COMMENT WITHIN THE CODE

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing warehouse</title>
    <style>
    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
            display: none;
    }

    #tooltip p {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
//NOTE:: x and y co-ordinates needs to be set on excel file.
//      width and height of rect needs to be set within functions returnheight and returnwidth

var width = 1500,
    height = 1500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var data    
d3.csv("AisleA.csv", function(d) {
  data = d;

    function returnwidth(bay)
    {
        //if odd bay then LS else Carton Flow. 
        //This fucntion keeps getting updated as we include other aisles and bays
        if(Number(bay) & 1)
        {
            // ODD
            return 40
        }
        else
        {
            // EVEN
            return 60
        }
    }

    function returnheight(bay)
    {
        if(Number(bay) & 1)
        {
            // ODD
            return 40
        }
        else
        {
            // EVEN
            return 60
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        svg.append("rect")
          .attr("x", data[i].x) 
          .attr("y", data[i].y)
          .attr("width", returnwidth(data[i].Bay))
          .attr("height", returnheight(data[i].Bay))
          .style("fill","green")    
          .style("stroke","black")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
            var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"))/2 //+ xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 //+ h / 2;
            console.log(data[i]) // ISSUE HERE. VALUE SHOWN AS UNDEFINED
            //Update the tooltip position and value
            d3.select("#tooltip")
              .style("left", xPosition + "px")
              .style("top", yPosition + "px")
              .select("#value")
              .text(data[i].PickRate); //ISSUE HERE

            //Show the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

            })
           .on("mouseout", function() {
            //Hide the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
            });                                                 
    }
});

</script>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <p><strong>Important Label Heading</strong></p>
        <p><span id="value">100</span>%</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The data that i need to display within the tool tip is in data[i]. Can some one please suggest me how i can access this data and display

CSV:

```
Aisle,Bay,PickRate,ReplenRate,x,y
A,1,medium,low,20,60
A,2,medium,high,20,120
A,3,low,low,80,60
A,4,high,low,100,120
A,5,medium,danger,140,60
A,6,danger,low,180,120
```

Working code - Tool tip adjustment

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing warehouse</title>
    <style>
    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
            display: none;
    }

    #tooltip p {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
//NOTE:: x and y co-ordinates needs to be set on excel file.
//      width and height of rect needs to be set within functions returnheight and returnwidth

var width = 1500,
    height = 1500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var data    
d3.csv("AisleA.csv", function(d) {
    data = d;
    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d){return d.x}) 
      .attr("y", function(d){return d.y})

        //IF ODD BAY THEN LS ELSE CARTON FLOW. 
        //THIS BELOW FUCNTION KEEPS GETTING UPDATED AS WE INCLUDE OTHER AISLES AND BAYS
      .attr("width", function(d){
            if(Number(d.Bay) & 1)
            {
                // ODD
                return 40
            }
            else
            {
                // EVEN
                return 60
            }
      })
      .attr("height", function(d){
            if(Number(d.Bay) & 1)
            {
                // ODD
                return 40
            }
            else
            {
                // EVEN
                return 60
            }
      })
      .style("fill","green")    //SHOULD CHANGE BASED ON THE PICK RATE VALUE
      .style("stroke","black")
      .on("mouseover", function(data) {
        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"))/2 //+ xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 //+ h / 2;

        //UPDATE THE TOOLTIP POSITION AND VALUE
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")
          .select("#value")
          .text(data.PickRate);

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

        })
       .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
        });                                                 
});

</script>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <p><strong>Important Label Heading</strong></p>
        <p><span id="value">100</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you also post the AisleA.csv

Comment: Sure.. will post along with the code

Comment: This is not the way d3 works. Instead on looping through the data array, you should "attach" the data to the rectangle, via `.data` function. I suggest you try this tutorial: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Comment: Thanks mef. Resolved it. Just have one more issue. Can you please tell me why the tool tip arent displaying on top of rectangles.. Updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the tooltip as per your calculation as shown below:

```
  var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
  var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) - 55;
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FD4dSPi9CmI3LGVq0HEw?p=preview):